# Retrieving image data URi from HTTP response

Tags: javascript, html, image

**The Problem**: Imagine I have a `td` element structured as such:

```
<td td="" colspan="2">
  <br>
   <img src="ImageServlet" alt="random image" border="0" id="simpleRandomImg">      
 </td>
```

of course, with other HTML around it.  The image contained within the servlet doesn't have a useful `src` indicated in the HTML (clearly) - however, when I open up the Network tab in Chrome, I can preview the loaded image itself and copy the image as a data URI - which gives me a stable URL like:

```
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAMgAAAAyCAIAAACWMwO2AAAhQklEQVR42u2dB1Sb5/nonTRt2pPkJGmSNm180zhNTkabuPGKMeAwxBaIJYEYWmhLSEIggRhaaAIaIEASEggQew+zzPLEdjyy07T/9t9129t129u9z7mP9LnfXxZCBuLeS/71c77zIRQCGj89z+993+d7vS/GH7GxsXH+wGAwCf5ITExMSkpKTk5OSUlJTU1N80d6etcetcetc...
```

so, clearly there exists a stable reference to the loaded image.  And clearly my browser 'knows' what that reference is, because I can retrieve the link to it as a data URI - but there's no reference to that data URI in the actual HTTP response.  This probably seems a lot less mystical to someone who understands JavaScript, but that someone is not myself - so could someone explain what's going on here, and if there is some way to gather the data image URI from the HTTP response?

**Attemped Solutions**: 
Did a little digging around in the HTTP response and located this bit of JavaScript which, apparently, handles the changing of images:

```
function changeImage() {
 // makes a new image load
 var obj=document.getElementById('simpleRandomImg');
 if (obj != null) {
  // append a unique index to force browser to reload
    obj.src='ImageServlet?'+(cnt++);
    }
```

However, nothing I see there gives any indication as to the actual URI location *of* the image.  As before, if I open the Google Chrome network tab and attempt to retrieve the data image URI from the individual response, it works and gives me a valid URI - so, clearly the browser is receiving it.  How can I access it?

e: to be clear, I do not control the website in question, so I can't 'fix' it by just changing the internal javascript - I'm viewing the site and am interested in whether or not it's possible to retrieve the loaded images short of screenshotting the page itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work. Canvas API has a function called toDataURI

```
function getDataUri(url, callback) {
    var image = new Image();

    image.onload = function () {
        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        canvas.width = this.naturalWidth; // or 'width' if you want a special/scaled size
        canvas.height = this.naturalHeight; // or 'height' if you want a special/scaled size

        canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(this, 0, 0);

        // Get raw image data
        callback(canvas.toDataURL('image/jpg').replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, ''));

        // ... or get as Data URI
        callback(canvas.toDataURL('image/jpg'));
    };

    image.src = url;
}

// Usage
// beware of server cors settings..
getDataUri('image url here', function(dataUri) {
    console.log(dataUri)
    // Do whatever you'd like with the Data URI!
});
```

Comment: I appreciate the effort, but doesn't this assume that I know the image's URL? The whole issue is that I *don't* have that information, and am trying to retrieve it.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `src` of the image to your `URI` by using `setAttribute`, like so:

`obj.setAttribute('src', uriString)`

Comment: sorry if I don't fully understand the answer, but to be clear - I don't control the site in question, which I think this answer assumes.

Comment: Is the issue that the image is not displaying on the page?

Comment: The image displays on the page, but only as `   <img src="ImageServlet" alt="random image" border="0" id="simpleRandomImg">      ` - I have to go to the Network tab in developer tools to retrieve an actual valid image URI.

Comment: Ok. What happens if you `console.log()` `ImageServlet`?

Comment: `> console.log() ImageServlet`
`VM676:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`